# Swap table rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am trying to do like this,

```
<table>
    <tr id="ID1"><td></td></tr>
    <tr id="ID2"><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

I need to swap table rows index position like as follows

```
<table>
    <tr id="ID2"><td></td></tr>
    <tr id="ID1"><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

I tried to fix it using jQuery as:

```
$('#ID1').after('#ID2');
```

Can anyone help me to fix the above requirement using javascript?

```js
$('#ID1').after('#ID2');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="ID1">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="ID2">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`after()` is used to insert content. To move or add elements, use `insertAfter()`:

```
$('#ID1').insertAfter('#ID2');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sbkL785c/)

Comment: `after` *can* move things, but it doesn't if you give it a string. `$('#ID2').after($('#ID1'));` works, for instance: http://jsfiddle.net/sbkL785c/1/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good point. `inserAfter` is cleaner though as it just takes the selector.

Comment: Yes. (And in general, `insertAfter` tends to be clearer to me anyway.) I was quite surprised by the OP's `after` behavior, though -- the docs suggest the two are just converses of each other, when clearly that's not *quite* the case.

Answer (score 0):

Swap row by appendChild.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("first");
var table = document.getElementById("table");
table.appendChild(x);
```

```html
 <table id="table">
    <tr id="first"><td>First</td></tr>
    <tr id="second"><td>Second</td></tr>
 </table>
```